# Traduction de « sworn upon » dans « It should be studied and weighed; admired, indeed, but not sworn upon »

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, anglais, science, religion

Je souhaite rendre en français :

> Newton's Principia should be studied and weighed; admired, indeed, but not sworn upon.
>   (Clifford Truesdell, 1968)

Voici ma phrase :

> Le Principia de Newton devrait être étudié et pesé; admiré, en effet, mais pas assermenté.

Assermenté rend-il correctement le sens du « sworn upon » dans ce contexte ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Avec la mise en contexte apportée par la [réponse de LPH](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/32358/364), il me vient:

> Il ne faut pas prendre ce livre pour *parole d'Évangile*.

Answer (score 3):

La référence qui est faite dans cette phrase est la pratique dans le monde anglo-saxon de jurer sur la bible et cela dans des occasions variées qui n'ont rien à voir avec le rite religieux; il ne s'agit pas d'assermenter la bible mais de donner une preuve de grande probité intellectuelle, politique, ou autre. Il ne s'agit pas donc d'assermenter l'ouvrage (en le présent cas, celui de Newton); il s'agit « de ne pas jurer par qqc ». Il faudrait dire quelque chose comme « Il ne faut pas jurer par le Principia Mathematica de Newton. ».

On trouve la définition suivante de « to swear *by, on, upon* » dans le dictionnaire d'Oxford.

v.i. Appeal to a god or other sacred person or thing in confirmation of the truth of a solemn declaration or statement. Now usually followed by « *by, on, upon* ».

Comment: Avec cette mise en contexte, il me vient _Il ne faut pas prendre ce livre pour parole d'Évangile_, mais le sens me semble différent.

Comment: @mouviciel Non, le sens me semble très exactement le même; l'idée est seulement abordée par un autre biais, qui ne nous change pas du domaine de la parole divine; cette possibilité a au moins des chances égales d'être une bonne traduction. Vous auriez peut être dû risquer une réponse, ce qu'il n'est possiblement pas trop tard de faire.

Comment: Voilà qui est fait.

Answer (score 1):

Phrase fondée  partialement sur la réponse de @LPH

> Le Principia de Newton devrait être étudié et pesé; admiré, certes, mais il ne faut jurer par cet ouvrage.

Autres phrases que j'ai conçues :

> Le Principia de Newton devrait être étudié et pesé; admiré, certes, mais il ne faut l'idolâtrer (merci @Laure).
>
> Le Principia de Newton devrait être étudié et pesé; admiré, certes, mais il ne faut pas le considérer comme la bible de Mécanique.
>
> Le Principia de Newton devrait être étudié et pesé; admiré, certes, mais il ne faut pas le prendre pour la vérité absolue.
>
> ...il ne faut pas le mettre sur un piédestal
>
> ...il ne faut pas le sacraliser.

(Pour les deux dernières merci @Greg)