# Idolâtrer : est-il reconnu ?

Tags: usage, grec

Si l'on dit en français la phrase :

> Le Principia de Newton devrait être étudié et pesé; admiré, certes, mais il ne faut l'idolâtrer.

(question connexe [Traduction de « sworn upon » dans « It should be studied and weighed; admired, indeed, but not sworn upon »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/32356/traduction-de-sworn-upon-dans-it-should-be-studied-and-weighed-admired-i))

sera-t-on compris ?

Le mot idole et les dérivés idolâtrer, idolâtre, idolâtré, idolâtrie sont-ils répandus/reconnus/courants ?

Comment: Avec une phrase pareille... Ce n'est pas forcément *idolâtré* qu'ils n'ont pas compris... :-) No disrespect meant!

Comment: @Laure À propos : c'était un enseignant/chercheur de philosophie, locuteur natif du français, qui m'a suggéré d'utiliser cette tournure.

Comment: @Laure : Peut-être j'ai mal compris mon collègue.

Comment: @aCOSwt Je viens de corriger et actualiser la question. Désolé.

Comment: @Laure Merci. Je viens de reformuler la question.

Comment: @Laure. Merci encore. Je viens de corriger ma réponse ici : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/32356/traduction-de-sworn-upon-dans-it-should-be-studied-and-weighed-admired-i

Comment: Ma réponse ne se placera pas au niveau de la langue (sauf pour dire que je suis étonnée qu'ils ne connaissent pas) donc  je vais te faire une réponse chez Cosette. À + là-bas donc

Comment: Left it [there](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51921353#51921353).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Idole* est un mot courant en français. On le rencontre surtout pour parler de vedettes (ex: *Justin Bieber est l'idole des jeunes filles*), mais plus tellement dans son sens original de "statuette ou image religieuse".

Les dérivés *idolâtrie*, *idolâtrer*, etc. appartiennent plutôt au registre littéraire et sont peu courants dans l'usage de tous les jours.

Pour votre exemple, si l'on parle d'un ouvrage scientifique, on pourrait dire plus couramment:

> il ne faut pas le mettre sur un piédestal
>
> il ne faut pas le sacraliser

(anecdote personnelle: je me souviens très bien de la première fois où, enfant, j'ai lu le mot "idolâtrer" la premère fois et que j'ai demandé sa signification à mes parents: c'était dans une bande dessinée, dans la bouche d'un majordome qui utilisait un langage toujours très châtié, ce qui ajoutait un léger effet comique)

Comment: Donc les jeunes utilisent bien encore le mot *idole*, ce n'est pas vieilli dans ce sens ?

Comment: Un petit coup d'oeil sur le forum de jeuxvideo.com (un corpus inestimable sur le langage des djeuns) semble en tout cas le valider. Un exemple: http://www.jeuxvideo.com/forums/42-51-60687492-1-0-1-0-l-enfer-d-etre-une-idole-kpop.htm

Comment: Merci. Je ne fréquente pas ce genre de site effectivement, mais ça peut être une bonne ressource !

Comment: Merci beaucoup ! Je les ai incluses aussi ici : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/32356/traduction-de-sworn-upon-dans-it-should-be-studied-and-weighed-admired-i

Answer (score 0):

*Idolâtrer*, c'est vraiment aimer ou respecter excessivement : l'idolâtrie n'est pas du tout une démarche scientifique, elle est uniquement émotionnelle.

On va idolâtrer une personne, parce qu'elle représente le summum des qualités qu'on apprécie, et que personne d'autre ne pourrait se substituer à elle dans notre esprit.

En revanche, il ne faut pas idolâtrer un traité de mathématiques, parce que la science progresse tous les jours et que ce qu'on présumait vrai hier peut se révéler erroné ou incomplet demain.

Mais il est permis de l'étudier et de l'admirer, surtout s'il représentait le summum des connaissances humaines dans son domaine quand il a été publié.